# Почему не работает кнопка aiogram?

Tags: python, aiogram

Начал разбираться с ботами в телеграмм с использованием aiogram. Но не могу понять, что у меня не так с inline клавиатурой. При нажатии на кнопку появляется значек загрузки и ничего не происходит, что в моем коде не так.

```py
    async def tshirt_start(message: types.Message):
        # keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        for name in available_tshirt_names:
            keyboard.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=name,callback_data=name))
        await message.answer("Выберите футболку:", reply_markup=keyboard)
        await OrderTshirt.waiting_for_tshirt_name.set()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно написать обработчик callback'ов. [**Вот**](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/callback_data_factory.py) хороший пример от самого `aiogram`.